# Prior, Posterior and Bayes rule for discrete random variables. Calculating Posteriors?

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior

For the discrete case in the image below below, could someone explain why a density, $f(x)$, is used rather than a pmf, $p(x)$. My notes say that, for most cases the value of the parameter takes continuous values, however when considering some distribution where $x$ takes discrete values, would we just swap $f(x)$ for $p(x)$?

Could anyone provide an example of such a case?

[image]

Additionally can someone vet my thought process here please: This idea holds when considering the binomial distribution modelling the number of successes $X$ where $X ~ B(n,p)$ because $p$ has to take values between $(0,1)$ and is thus continuous on this interval and thus $f(p)$ can be used as the prior, rather than $P(p)$?

Comment: In your problem description, did you mean to write $\theta$ instead of x? AFAICT for discrete xs, the cited text uses $p(x)$ already, and you seem to be talking about the parameter, not data.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did. I did not know how to write $theta$, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Wrapping text with the dollar signs lets you use MathJax; to get the Greek letters in particular, you can use a backslash followed by the letter name.

Comment: They are assuming (as is usually the case, though not always) that $\theta$ is continuous, while $x$ is either discrete or continuous. e.g. consider a binomial or a Poisson model (both have discrete random variables for the observations and continuous parameter).

Comment: Yes this makes sense thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, your parameter only takes discrete values, you could essentially fake it as being a continuous distribution, where the non-integer-valued points are assigned a probability of zero. In other words, the p.d.f. looks something like a sum of Dirac deltas.

In this case, p.d.f. and p.m.f. are interchangeable, and you can replace integration with a simple sum. Pearl's *Causality* notably favors sum notation to look less intimidating to people who are not too keen on calculus.

And yeah - the *realizations* of the probability are binary, but the actual parameter of the Binomial is continuous. The prior is usually described with a Beta distribution, to be specific.